# Как сделать плавный переход с псведоклассами CSS

Tags: html, css

Задача такова: Чтоб картинка справа(Луна) плавно при наведении пошла налево к Земле.
hover пробовал ток работат маргином лефт а вот райт не работает.
[image]

Comment: Ну и где код???

Answer (score 1):

Дайте луне свойство `transition: (тут имя свойство, которое будет изменяться, например transform) 2s;` при hover меняйте свойство.

```
transform: translateX(-250px)
position: absolute; left:-250px/30% или вообще calc()
animation: moon linear 2s; (тут пишите анимацию какую хотите) если используете animation:... - тогда transition луне не нужно давать
```

Вариантов масса на вкус и цвет